# Ansible : How to run a role in one specific host

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have a playbook , which is calling several roles and execute them in several hosts:

**My playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    - selected_APIS: "{{ RCD_APIS.split(',') }}"
  pre_tasks:
    - name : Display selected micro-services
      run_once: true
      debug:
        msg: "{{selected_APIS}}"
  roles:
    - { role: pullDockerImages , when: '"PULL" in DEPL_MODE'}
    - { role: stopDockerContainers , when: '"STOP" in DEPL_MODE'}
    - { role: pullDockerConFiles , when: '"START" in DEPL_MODE'}  // THIS ROLE
    - { role: prepareDirectoriesTree , when: '"START" in DEPL_MODE'}  
    - { role: startDockerContainers , when: '"START" in DEPL_MODE'}
```

**My purpose is that :**

i want to run the third role only on **localhost** / or a specific one host

*how may i do it??*

I ve tried to add `"hosts: localhost"` to my tasks in that role , but that failed , i ve tried also `delegate_to: localhost` and `local_action` , but all those failed.

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: What is the use case? Seems like and XY problem

Comment: I tried it right now, and it works perfectly. What is your exact problem? Do you receive a `permission denied`?  If so, please update the question, and I might be able to help.

Comment: @ThomasBöhm what exactly goes well with u ?

Comment: @firasKoubaa using `localhost` as parameter for `hosts:` in a playbook. You can (in your code posted above) change `hosts: all` to `hosts: localhost`

Answer (score 3):

You need to list all hosts in inventory file, also localhost, for example

```
[sandbox]
localhost    ansible_connection=local
other1.example.com    ansible_connection=ssh
other2.example.com    ansible_connection=ssh
```

Then in your playbook, you need to reference to localhost by index, in my case localhost has an index 0, that why we can write like this

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    - selected_APIS: "{{ RCD_APIS.split(',') }}"
  pre_tasks:
    - name : Display selected micro-services
      run_once: true
      debug:
        msg: "{{selected_APIS}}"
  roles:
    - { role: pullDockerImages , when: '"PULL" in DEPL_MODE and inventory_hostname != play_hosts[0]'}
    - { role: stopDockerContainers , when: '"STOP" in DEPL_MODE and inventory_hostname != play_hosts[0]'}
    - { role: pullDockerConFiles , when: '"START" in DEPL_MODE and inventory_hostname == play_hosts[0]'}  // THIS ROLE
    - { role: prepareDirectoriesTree , when: '"START" in DEPL_MODE and inventory_hostname != play_hosts[0]'}  
    - { role: startDockerContainers , when: '"START" in DEPL_MODE and inventory_hostname != play_hosts[0]'}
```

As a result 3rd role will be run only on the localhost, non of other roles will not be run on localhost.